# Move UIImage's around UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have this code works perfectly, But when I add zoom to the UIScrollView, I can't move the image around the scroll, the images do not respond to event drag

What I can do?

```
 --h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DragView : UIImageView
{
CGPoint previousLocation;

}

@end


--m file

#import "DragView.h"

@implementation DragView

- (id) initWithImage: (UIImage *) anImage
{
    if (self = [super initWithImage:anImage])
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        self.gestureRecognizers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pan,nil];

    }

    return self;
}


// Promote touched view
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    previousLocation = self.center;

}


// Move view
- (void) handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)uigr
{
    CGPoint translation = [uigr translationInView:uigr.view];
    uigr.view.center=CGPointMake(uigr.view.center.x+translation.x, uigr.view.center.y+ translation.y);
    [uigr setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:uigr.view];
}

@end
```

**And here use the clase to create the image. with the event drag**

```
NSMutableArray *arregloImagenes;

DragView *mesas1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    arregloImagenes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    mesas1 = [[DragView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mesa.png"]];
    mesas1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    [_propVistaCentral addSubview:mesas1];
    [_propVistaCentral bringSubviewToFront:mesas1];

    _scroll.minimumZoomScale=1;
    _scroll.maximumZoomScale=3;

}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    return _propVistaCentral;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with these properties

```
_scroll.delaysContentTouches=YES;
_scroll.canCancelContentTouches=NO;
```

Because y need move first the imagen before it enters the scroll event

Answer (score 0):

You could try subclassing UIScrollView and implement the touchesShouldCancelInContentView: method to return NO for your DragView and YES otherwise, something like:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return ([view class] != [DragView class]);
}
```